# Problema con 'La conversión especificada no es válida' en ASP.NET (dato tipo INT)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, windows-forms

Me encuentro desarrollando una aplicación en ASP.NET y tengo el siguiente problema:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'La conversión especificada no es válida.'

Esto se produce a la hora de recibir un dato INT en mi método de **BuscarUsuario**

**Mi entidad:**

```
public class Usuario
{
    public Usuario() { }
    [DataMember]
    public int IdUsuario { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50), MinLength(3)]
    [DataMember]
    public string Apellidos { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Direccion { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Telefono { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime Fecha_Ingreso { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Clave { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<Usuario> usuarios { get; set; }

}
```

**BuscarUsuario:**

```
public Usuario BuscarUsuario(int IdUsuario)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_ListarUsuario", cnx.Conexion());
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@pIdUsuario", SqlDbType.Int); // revisar luego
        cmd.Parameters["@pIdUsuario"].Value = IdUsuario;
        cnx.AbrirConexion();
        SqlDataReader registro = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
        if (registro.HasRows)
        {
            while (registro.Read())
            {
                usuario.IdUsuario = registro.GetInt32(0);
                usuario.Nombre = registro.GetString(1);
                usuario.Apellidos = registro.GetString(2);
                usuario.Direccion = registro.GetString(3);
                usuario.Email = registro.GetString(4);
                usuario.Fecha_Ingreso = registro.GetDateTime(5);
            }
        }
        else { usuario = null; }
        registro.Close();
        cnx.CerrarConexion();
        return usuario;
    }
```

**Botón de Buscar:**

```
protected void BtnBuscar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (TxtIdUsuario.Text.Length > 0)
            {
                user = usuario.BuscarUsuario(Convert.ToInt32(TxtIdUsuario.Text));
                if (user == null)
                {
                    HabilitarNuevo();
                    btnGuardar.Text = "Guardar";
                }
                else
                {
                    DateTime fecha = user.Fecha_Ingreso;
                    TxtNombre.Text = user.Nombre;
                    TxtApellidos.Text = user.Apellidos;
                    TxtDireccion.Text = user.Direccion;
                    TxtEmail.Text = user.Email;
                    TxtFechaIngreso.Text = String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", fecha);
                    HabilitarEdicionBorrado();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),
                        "alert", "alert('¡El campo IdUsuario no puede quedar vacio!')", true);
                LimpiarTexto();

            }
        }
```

**Así obtengo el Id:**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TxtIdUsuario" class="form-control"
                         runat="server" placeholder="Usuario ID" type="number"></asp:TextBox>
```

Estuve rato buscando alguna solución para este error pero no logro encontrarlo, sé que se debe a la conversión de los datos, ya que el error me lo da en la linea de `usuario.IdUsuario = registro.GetInt32(0);` del método **BuscarUsuario**.

Sin embargo, no me quedé con sólo esa opción y cambié esa linea por `usuario.IdUsuario = Convert.ToInt32(registro["IdUsuario"].ToString());` pero recibí otro error, el cual es:

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'IdUsuario'

Entonces no sé a que se pueda deber el error. Espero que me puedan resolver este problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma rápida y de **sentido común** para solucionar tu problema, es **no realizar la asignación donde te da el error**. El `IdUsuario` **ya lo tienes como parámetro**, **no hace falta que lo asignes desde la BD**, ya que será el mismo (por ser PK).

Prueba esto:

```
        while (registro.Read())
        {
            // usuario.IdUsuario = registro.GetInt32(0);
            usuario.IdUsuario = IdUsuario;
            usuario.Nombre = registro.GetString(1);
            usuario.Apellidos = registro.GetString(2);
            usuario.Direccion = registro.GetString(3);
            usuario.Email = registro.GetString(4);
            usuario.Fecha_Ingreso = registro.GetDateTime(5);
        }
```

A veces los errores se solucionan **evitándolos**.

Comment: Funciona perfectamente, de hecho estuve pensando hasta en probar eliminando la linea completa, pero no se me había ocurrido igualarlo al mismo parámetro. Muchas gracias.